# Total Validator doesn't find skip link

Tags: html, validation, accessibility

Total Validator doesn't find this link and write this warning to me:

> Add a skip navigation link as the first link on the page.

How can I write this link in a better way?

```html
<html>
<body>
<a href="#skip">Skip to Content</a>
navbar with menu 
<div id="skip">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding `id="skiptocontent"` on the anchor link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have tested, they do require the text link to contain the word "skip", and the `href` attribute to start with a `#`, no matter if this element exists.

With the code you have submitted, it works with my own installation of TotalValidator (I am not saying that I would use this tool).

For information, TotalValidator web site uses the following code

```
<div id="skip"><a href="#content">Skip navigation</a></div>

[...]

<a id="content"></a>
```

Comment: You are right: you have to put the word "skip" in the beginning of the <a> tag content. If you are writing a site in other language than english, you can put this word "skip" in a non visible <span> tag, inside the <a> tag.

Answer (score 0):

In spite of what the first comment says, the ID value "skip" is technically fine; it does not need to be changed to "skiptocontent". The reason why TotalValidator does not detect the skip link is probably something else. The link goes to somewhere in the page, and that "somewhere" is not explicitly marked as the main content. You can do this using [WAI-ARIA landmarks](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#dfn-landmark).

With markup such as the following, it should be obvious for a validator that your first link is a skip link to the main content:

```
<body>
  <a href="#skip">Skip to Content</a>
  <!-- navigation menu goes here -->
  <div role="main" id="skip">
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

You can also use "semantic" elements, e.g.

```
<body>
  <a href="#skip">Skip to Content</a>
  <header><h1>...</h1></header>
  <nav><!-- navigation menu goes here --></nav>
  <main id="skip"><!--role="main" is redundant on the main element-->
    <p>...</p>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

See the WAI-ARIA specification for documentation on [main (role)](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#main) and the HTML5.2 spec for the [main element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/grouping-content.html#the-main-element).